# Communication with GPIB Card

Tags: delphi, gpib

I am using a GP-IB card with delphi 10. I cant figure out how to "set up" the install so I can get delphi to communicate with the card.

Card is http://www.contec.com/product.php?id=1146

What are the steps for getting it to communicate with outside device?
What dll file do I add?
What is a basic 1 button program that would just check if GPIB card was installed?

I hope I am asking this right, I could really use an into to how to do this communication.

Comment: Does card producer offer some driver for this card and DLL to communicate using device API? What software you have got with the card?

Comment: @MBo Yes I installed teh drivers and software but no idea what DLL to add to delphi. The producer (contec) , i have looked at there website and manuals. Cant figure out what i need to add to use this. The software is API-PAC(w32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to install this software, but see that help contains functions' description like this

```
GpTalkEx
Operation            Transmits data. When transmits binary data by VB, use GpTalkExBinary..

Format                (C)

DWORD Srlen, Ret;
DWORD * Cmd;
char * Srbuf;

Ret = GpTalkEx(Cmd, &Srlen, Srbuf);
```

You have to find what DLL do these functions refer to - search in .bas or .h header files. Then translate header file to Delphi (.pas variant might be provided by producer) like this (static import variant)

```
function GpTalkEx(Cmd: DWord; var Srlen: DWord; Srbuf: PChar):DWord; 
                  cdecl; external 'GPIB.dll'; // I've used arbitrary name
```

and use functions in your program.